# RSA Decryption: Doubts: knowing p or $\phi(n)$ can lead to find private exponent?

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

I have some doubts about RSA (the public key $n$ and $e$ is public):

Note $n = pq$ and $\phi (n) = (p-1)(q-1)$

- 1) Say if some hacker knew $p$, why would it be easy for them to find $q, \phi (n), d$?

$d$ is a prime larger than $p, q$ so that $1 = k\cdot \phi(n) + d\cdot e$

- 2) Now, say if a hacker knew $\phi (n)$, why would it be easy to find $p,q,d$?

Comment: BTW: in general, $d$ needn't be prime (and, for that matter, it isn't always the case that there exists an integer $k$ s.t. $1 = k \cdot \phi(n) + d \cdot e$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - 1) Say if some hacker knew $p$, why would it be easy for them to find $q, \phi (n), d$?

Since $n = p \cdot q $ this implies $q$ is also known by simple division $p = n/q$.

Then $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ is known

By using $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \phi(n)$ then $d$ is known. This can be found by the extended Euclidean algorithm.

> $d$ is a prime larger than $p, q$ so that $1 = k\cdot \phi(n) + d\cdot e$

$d$ doesn't need to be prime. It can be larger or smaller than the $p$ and $q$ depend on the value of $e,p,q$.

> - 2) Now, say if a hacker knew $\phi (n)$, why would it be easy to find $p,q,d$?

$d$ is as above.

**1. Method with the knowledge of** $\phi (n)$

$\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = (n + 1)- (p+q) $ implies $$p+q = (n +1) - \phi(n)$$ and

$$q = (n+1) - \phi(n) - p $$ since we have $$ n = pq $$ substitue

$$n = p \left ( n + 1 - \phi{(n)} - p \right ) = -p^2 + (n + 1 - \phi{(n)})p$$
 $$p^2 - (n + 1 - \phi{(n)})p + n = 0$$

Now, we got a quadratic equation that can be solved by the quadratic polynomial root-finding formula;$$p = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}.$$ Using the formula one gets;

$$p = \frac{(n + 1 - \phi{(n)}) \pm \sqrt{(n + 1 - \phi{(n)})^2 - 4n}}{2}$$

Therefore the knowledge of the $\phi(n)$ enables factoring the $n$ in constant time, $\mathcal{O}(1)$

**2. Method with the knowledge of** $\phi (n)$

- $(p+q)$ can be obtained from $n$ and $\phi(n)$ as $$\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = n - (p+q) +1$$
- $(p-q)$ can be obtained from $(p+q)^2-4n$, since $(p-q)$ is the square root of it.

  Then one can find $q$ as $$q = \frac{(p+q)-(p-q)}{2}.$$